# Why is "WinMain" unresolved when linked as a *.a static library?

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

Given a simple program:

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hInstPrev, 
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
  return 0;
}
```

If I run `g++ a.cpp` it works fine.

However, running `g++ -c a.cpp && ar rcs a.a a.o && g++ a.a` gives the following error:

```
c:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x39): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any insight as to why this occurs? How can I link a program with only .a files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The gcc `ld` linker handles `*.a` static libraries a little differently from `*.o` object files. In particular, symbols from the static library *do not* get included into the final binary image executable unless an object file or another static library linked in earlier uses it.

Additionally, the order you pass in the static libraries matter for `ld`. For example, say `libb.a` needs a function that's in `liba.a`. If you link it like so:

> g++ -Wall example.cpp -o example.exe -la -lb

This will fail to resolve because when `liba` is processed it doesn't see what symbols `-lb` requires (`libb` hasn't been processed yet). The only symbols retrieved from `liba.a` is everything it has seen up to *that point*.

### Why is this important?

If you apply the above process to your question it becomes clear why `WinMain` isn't getting resolved.

> g++ a.a

When `ld` processes `a.a` it says *"oh nothing is using `WinMain` so I won't include it"*; and that is true up that point of processing since no other object files are provided before it.

What you don't see above is that mingw, by default, ***also includes*** a bunch of important boilerplate code needed for your program to work. One of these is `crt0_c.o` from `mingw32.a` which makes up part of the mingw runtime that *does* call your `WinMain`.

### Solutions

There are two ways to ensure that `WinMain` from your `a.a` gets included:

1. Use `-Wl,--whole-archive` to force inclusion of all symbols in `a.a` so they're available for symbol resolution. Append `-Wl,--no-whole-archive` afterwards so it doesn't erroneously apply this to other libraries that comes after. eg.

   ```
   g++ -o example.exe -Wl,--whole-archive a.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
   ```
2. The second way is to include `mingw32.a` manually *before* `a.a` so `WinMain` becomes a pending unresolved symbol when `a.a` is processed:

   ```
   g++ -o example.exe -lmingw32 a.a
   ```

   or

   ```
   g++ -o example.exe libmingw32.a a.a
   ```

But you'll probably need to fully qualify the path to `libmingw32.a` or else the linker won't find it.

Answer (score 0):

.a files are static libraries, as far as the linker is concerned. The linker only takes objects out of the archives that define symbols that are currently unresolved. Thus, without any object files referencing symbols defined in the .a files, they won't be pulled in. The linker output in your example is empty, thus WinMain is not defined.

Actually it appears to work when you define the standard main(). I assume that's because of there being a reference to main() required by the language standard. There is also a gcc / ld command line option to generate a reference to a symbol. Try adding `-u WinMain@16` before the .a file.

Comment: So compiling an executable with WinMain inside .a is simply impossible?

Comment: I've edited in a possible way to do that, though I don't know what the whole point of this. All the .a archives are generally libraries and it is unusual and confusing to put your actual program in those, including the main function no less.

Comment: `g++ -u WinMain@16 a.a` doesn't work. I use .a files in my project to modularize my code. Say, I have subdirectories "core", "graphics", "input", each directory builds itself independently, has its object files archived, then the final project should be able to link together the archive files.

Comment: @user1641398 it's ok to use .a for modules, just don't put your entry point into these. Make `main` (or `WinMain`, in your case) function out of static library in just an object file.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Code::Blocks. Today i have same problem with WinMain in static library. Changing order of libraries does not works in my case. I finally solved it by adding `-lmingw32` to ***Project/Build options/Linker settings/Other linker options*.**