# Compile from .o Files to .dll File in Linux

Tags: linux, dll, compilation

Im trying to compile/link .o file(s) into a .dll file under Ubuntu...

i get it nearly to work but i have a problem with static linking these .o file(s) ...

Here is what ive done:

First i installed all dependencies ... then i build the following application:

https://github.com/Zeranoe/mingw-w64-build

On my Ubuntu.

After that i create the .o files from the application with normal "sudo make" command...

Now i had all .o file(s) ready ... then i modified the .o files with "dlltool" so now i have the opportunity to link them to a .dll file with "mingw" ... it works only in "shared mode" ... not in "static mode" ...

this is the working command:

```
sudo /home/robert/Downloads/mingw-32/x86_64/i686/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -shared -lmsvcrt -Wl,-subsystem,windows *.o -o phpcppdll.dll
```

and this is not working:

```
sudo /home/robert/Downloads/mingw-32/x86_64/i686/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -static -lmsvcrt -Wl,-subsystem,windows *.o -o phpcppdll.dll
```

and then i get the following error - with this command:

```
/home/robert/Downloads/mingw-32/x86_64/i686/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/11.2.1/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /home/robert/Downloads/mingw-32/x86_64/i686/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/11.2.1/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but i dont get further maybe you have an idea ...

Comment: Is this related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/19625047/17635987

Comment: no it isnt - they dont compile with the mingw directly!

Answer (score 0):

Okay - i got it to work with the -nostartfiles flag ... but it dont make sense because all .dlls are not static ... but shared ...